# Interactive point labels with gridSVG and ggplot2 v.0.9.0

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'd like to label points in a ggplot interactively, so that mousing over a point shows a label.

I'm trying to adapt the answer given in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8972642/how-do-you-relate-ggplot2-grobs-back-to-the-data) so that it works in the latest version of ggplot2. Influenced by comments on the ggplot google group, [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/ggplot2/PujkP1QvvCM), I used the latest version of geom-point-.r as a template, adding a "label" field to the gp argument in various places. Then I copied the remaining code from kohske's answer. But it doesn't work -- there aren't any labels in the resulting svg, and I can't figure out why.

I did notice that everything in `point_grobs_labels` is null, and when I look at `grid.get(point_grob_names[1])$gp`, there is no label field...

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gridSVG)
library(proto)
library(rjson)

geom_point2 <- function (mapping = NULL, data = NULL, stat = "identity", 
                         position = "identity",
                         na.rm = FALSE, ...) {
  ggplot2:::GeomPoint$new(mapping = mapping, data = data, stat = stat, 
                          position = position, 
                          na.rm = na.rm, ...)
}

GeomPoint2 <- proto(ggplot2:::Geom, {
  objname <- "point"

  draw_groups <- function(., ...) .$draw(...)
  draw <- function(., data, scales, coordinates, na.rm = FALSE, ...) {    
    data <- remove_missing(data, na.rm, 
                           c("x", "y", "size", "shape"), name = "geom_point")
    if (empty(data)) return(zeroGrob())

    with(coord_transform(coordinates, data, scales), 
         ggname(.$my_name(), pointsGrob(x, y, size=unit(size, "mm"), pch=shape, 
                                        gp=gpar(
                                          col=alpha(colour, alpha),
                                          fill = alpha(fill, alpha),  
                                          label = label, 
                                          fontsize = size * .pt)))
    )
  }

  draw_legend <- function(., data, ...) {
    data <- aesdefaults(data, .$default_aes(), list(...))

    with(data,
         pointsGrob(0.5, 0.5, size=unit(size, "mm"), pch=shape, 
                    gp=gpar(
                      col = alpha(colour, alpha), 
                      fill = alpha(fill, alpha), 
                      label = label,
                      fontsize = size * .pt)
         )
    )
  }

  default_stat <- function(.) StatIdentity
  required_aes <- c("x", "y")
  default_aes <- function(.) aes(shape=16, colour="black", size=2, 
                                 fill = NA, alpha = NA, label = NA)

})

p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, wt, label = rownames(mtcars))) + geom_point2() + facet_wrap(~ gear)
print(p)

grob_names <- grid.ls(print = FALSE)$name
point_grob_names <- sort(grob_names[grepl("point", grob_names)])
point_grobs_labels <- lapply(point_grob_names, function(x) grid.get(x)$gp$label)  

jlabel <- toJSON(point_grobs_labels)

grid.text("value", 0.05, 0.05, just = c(0, 0), name = "text_place", gp = gpar(col = "red"))

script <- '
var txt = null;
function f() {
var id = this.id.match(/geom_point2.([0-9]+)\\.points.*\\.([0-9]+)$/);
txt.textContent = label[id[1]-1][id[2]-1];
}

window.addEventListener("load",function(){
var es = document.getElementsByTagName("circle");
for (i=0; i<es.length; ++i) es[i].addEventListener("mouseover", f, false);

txt = (document.getElementById("text_place").getElementsByTagName("tspan"))[0];

},false);
'

grid.script(script = script)
grid.script(script = paste("var label = ", jlabel))

gridToSVG()
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try this:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gridSVG)
library(proto)
library(rjson)
mtcars2 <- data.frame(mtcars, names = rownames(mtcars))

geom_point2 <- function (...) {
  GeomPoint2$new(...)
}

GeomPoint2 <- proto(ggplot2:::Geom, {
  objname <- "point"

  draw_groups <- function(., ...) .$draw(...)
  draw <- function(., data, scales, coordinates, na.rm = FALSE, ...) {    
    data <- remove_missing(data, na.rm, 
                           c("x", "y", "size", "shape"), name = "geom_point")
    if (empty(data)) return(zeroGrob())
    name <- paste(.$my_name(), data$PANEL[1], sep = ".")
    with(coord_transform(coordinates, data, scales), 
         ggname(name, pointsGrob(x, y, size=unit(size, "mm"), pch=shape, 
                                        gp=gpar(
                                          col=alpha(colour, alpha),
                                          fill = alpha(fill, alpha),  
                                          label = label, 
                                          fontsize = size * .pt)))
    )
  }

  draw_legend <- function(., data, ...) {
    data <- aesdefaults(data, .$default_aes(), list(...))

    with(data,
         pointsGrob(0.5, 0.5, size=unit(size, "mm"), pch=shape, 
                    gp=gpar(
                      col = alpha(colour, alpha), 
                      fill = alpha(fill, alpha), 
                      label = label,
                      fontsize = size * .pt)
         )
    )
  }

  default_stat <- function(.) StatIdentity
  required_aes <- c("x", "y")
  default_aes <- function(.) aes(shape=16, colour="black", size=2, 
                                 fill = NA, alpha = NA, label = NA)

})

p <- ggplot(mtcars2, aes(mpg, wt, label = names)) + geom_point2() +facet_wrap(~ gear)
print(p)

grob_names <- grid.ls(print = FALSE)$name
point_grob_names <- sort(grob_names[grepl("point", grob_names)])
point_grobs_labels <- lapply(point_grob_names, function(x) grid.get(x)$gp$label)

jlabel <- toJSON(point_grobs_labels)

grid.text("value", 0.05, 0.05, just = c(0, 0), name = "text_place", gp = gpar(col = "red"))

script <- '
var txt = null;
function f() {
    var id = this.id.match(/geom_point.([0-9]+)\\.points.*\\.([0-9]+)$/);
    txt.textContent = label[id[1]-1][id[2]-1];
}

window.addEventListener("load",function(){
    var es = document.getElementsByTagName("circle");
    for (i=0; i<es.length; ++i) es[i].addEventListener("mouseover", f, false);

    txt = (document.getElementById("text_place").getElementsByTagName("tspan"))[0];

},false);
'
grid.script(script = paste("var label = ", jlabel))
grid.script(script = script)

gridToSVG()
```

there were no big changes, but I had to add

```
mtcars2 <- data.frame(mtcars, names = rownames(mtcars))
```

and then

```
p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, wt, label = rownames(mtcars)))
     + geom_point2() + facet_wrap(~ gear)
```

also changes to

```
p <- ggplot(mtcars2, aes(mpg, wt, label = names)) 
     + geom_point2() +facet_wrap(~ gear)
```

because we have `rownames(mtcars)`

```
rownames(mtcars)
 [1] "Mazda RX4"           "Mazda RX4 Wag"       "Datsun 710"          "Hornet 4 Drive"     
 [5] "Hornet Sportabout"   "Valiant"             "Duster 360"          "Merc 240D"          
 [9] "Merc 230"            "Merc 280"            "Merc 280C"           "Merc 450SE"
.....
```

and then labels (which we manage to get with other modifications) remain the same, i.e. not rearranged by `gears`, only split by it:

```
point_grobs_labels
[[1]]
 [1] "Mazda RX4"          "Mazda RX4 Wag"      "Datsun 710"         "Hornet 4 Drive"    
 [5] "Hornet Sportabout"  "Valiant"            "Duster 360"         "Merc 240D"         
 [9] "Merc 230"           "Merc 280"           "Merc 280C"          "Merc 450SE"        
[13] "Merc 450SL"         "Merc 450SLC"        "Cadillac Fleetwood"
[[2]]
....
```

but having these label names as a column fixes the problem.

```
point_grobs_labels 
[[1]]
 [1] "Hornet 4 Drive"      "Hornet Sportabout"   "Valiant"             "Duster 360"         
 [5] "Merc 450SE"          "Merc 450SL"          "Merc 450SLC"         "Cadillac Fleetwood" 
 [9] "Lincoln Continental" "Chrysler Imperial"   "Toyota Corona"       "Dodge Challenger"   
[13] "AMC Javelin"         "Camaro Z28"          "Pontiac Firebird"   

[[2]]
....
```

Comment: Nice! Thank you! I was looking for a full, working example just like this one. I have a couple of questions, though: what role does "proto" play in the script? You're using it to redefine geom_point, right?  I'm interested in creating interactive plots out of ggplot2 graphs I made . Can you recommend any tutorial/source on getting R to work with Javascript with RJSON and creating SVGs?

Comment: @MatteoS, Unfortunately, I can't help you much here, mainly I just tried to find a solution to this particular problem. But you might be right, possibly redefining `geom_point` allows us to use these labels, which I would call the base at least in this case. So, I would offer you to explore this example, especially Javascript, `grid.get()` and `grid.ls()` parts.

Comment: Thanks a lot Julius (and tracy for asking the question). Do you have any idea on how to adapt this approach to polygon geoms?

Comment: @ferrouswheel, not really, since at least for me this version no longer works even with points.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to tracy for a good question and Julius for the very helpful answer.

To make Julius's javascript work for me in Chrome and Safari, I had to replace `this.id` with `this.correspondingUseElement.id`.  This makes sense because the single `<circle>` SVG element doesn't have an id for each geom_point, the id we want is attached to the `<use>` elements.

Even that didn't work for me in Firefox, so I changed it to attach the event listener to the `<use>` elements themselves.  Note that if the SVG is more complicated, it might have `<use>`s other than the geom_points, so I added an `if` to only attach the event to the geom_point.XX `<use>` elements.  This works in Chrome, Safari, and Firefox for me:

```
window.addEventListener("load",function(){
  var es = document.getElementsByTagName("use"); 
  for (i=0; i<es.length; ++i) {
    if(es[i].id.search(/geom_point.([0-9]+)\.points.*\.([0-9]+)$/) >= 0) es[i].addEventListener("mouseover", f, false);
  }
  txt = (document.getElementById("text_place").getElementsByTagName("tspan"))[0];
},false);
```

(all other code same as Julius's)

Answer (score 0):

We solved this by detecting the color attribute in the produced .svg and using css to detect mouseover. Results are visible in steps 4,5,6 of this demo:

[Showing svg highlighting using css](http://kwiqly.com/demo)

This is my first stackoverflow response - hope I got the etiquette right

Answer (score 0):

This is sort of a general answer. I'm just here to help you make the plot interactive. You can try this -

```
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)

# Plot how you would normally code for ggplot2
p <- ggplot(data,... 'add your variables and subsequent plots')
ggplotly(p)
```

Enjoy!