# R does ggplot2 have interactivity option?

Tags: r, ggplot2, interactive

I have some data that I'd like to put in a scatter plot and when I rollover the point on the chart I'd like to have a bubble popup and give some identifying info.

For instance if I had a data frame with a students name, height and weight, I'd like to plot height and weight on the x and y axis respectively.  Then when I rollover an individual point on the plot a bubble would pop up with the students name.

There is a somewhat similar function used in a basic `plot()` called `identify()` but it requires clicking on the point and doesn't go away after I leave the point.

Here's a sample df and the plot/identify code:

```
> dput(df1)
structure(list(id = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10), var1 = c(0.469521932071075, 
0.077109789242968, 0.076340542640537, 0.461061101639643, 0.347079795086756, 
0.425340321380645, 0.738443679409102, 0.00931701785884798, 0.267918228404596, 
0.722170797875151), var2 = c(0.265150599181652, 0.557858553016558, 
0.715832461370155, 0.186717337928712, 0.626156869810075, 0.1359783844091, 
0.67408229294233, 0.528320853365585, 0.241800826275721, 0.80992470192723
), names = c("jim", "nancy", "suzy", "mark", "alex", "jen", "luz", 
"jeff", "paula", "amir")), .Names = c("id", "var1", "var2", "names"
), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = "data.frame")

plot(df1$var1, df1$var2);grid()
identify(df1$var1, df1$var2, labels = df1$names)
```

Here's an example after clicking on a few points:

[image]

Any suggestions?

Comment: The longer answer is probably it will, but not for a (long?) while. (I'm assuming an eventual convergence with d3.) In the meantime, you may be stuck with annotating SVGs (search the CRAN packages for SVG, and you'll find them). But I can tell you from experience that it's not very fun.

Comment: thanks. I appreciate the info.  Looks like googleVis package might be viable substitute.

Comment: Hadley has been working that and demoed something I can't remember the name of for interactive views of his `profr` package... but [this link](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/ggplot2/sHUxj16xu_c) has some other resources.

Comment: This does not work anymore but the result was similar to what you want and it might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11134379/interactive-point-labels-with-gridsvg-and-ggplot2-v-0-9-0

Comment: @joran Hadley has an r2d3 package up on github. Seems like he's been playing with the idea for a while now.

Comment: @screechOwl If you want this type of interactivity, at least from a web-based perspective you should consider learning d3. googleVis, is great but keep in mind that it sends proprietary or potentially private data to the google visualization api.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `HTKidentify` and `HWidentify` functions in the TeachingDemos package allow for the creation of a scatter plot and having information pop up when you hover the mouse over a data point, the information goes away when you move to a new point.  The first one requires Tk and the second one is only for windows and neither uses ggplot2 (but both are pure R code, so you may find a way to modify them to work with ggplot2 or other extensions).

Comment: Awesome package!  Thanks for the heads up!